# MariaDB C Connector insert date time

Tags: sql, c

I'm having trouble inserting datetime into mariadb using C.

```
    t = time(NULL);
    struct tm tm = *localtime(&t);
    sprintf(curTime, "%d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d", tm.tm_year + 1900, tm.tm_mon + 1, tm.tm_mday, tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec);
    sprintf(sql, "INSERT INTO dataTable (sn, date, value_1, value_2) VALUES (%s,%s,%.1f,%.1f)", rxsn, curTime, temp, hud);
```

Output sql:

```
    INSERT INTO dataTable (sn, date, value_1, value_2) VALUES (fb8e2ffb, 2022-09-18 19:04:28,21.6,61.1)
```

And I get this:

```
    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '19:04:28,21.6,61.1)' at line 1
```

I tried different combinations and still nothing.
Thank you

Comment: This may not pertain and will demonstrate my ignorance of `C`, but are you able to put single quotes around the date and see if that works?

Comment: you should take a look at the examples on the mariadb webpage before starting see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/bulk-insert-row-wise-binding/